# Oracle SQL : Need help how below can be fetched

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

I have 2 tables. One is Data table and another is Mapping table. Mapping table contains fields like TYPE,ATTRIBUTE and DESTINATION. Mapping table tells, for particular TYPE, which attribute presents in which column in data table

DATA_TABLE

```
TYPE    Data_field1    data_field2   data_field3  
-------------------------------------------------
abc       1234           5678         4321         
def       5679           1235         9877
```

Mapping_Table

```
TYPE     Attribute    destination
--------------------------------------
abc      emp_id           data_field1
abc      dept_id          data_field2
abc      ph_no            data_field3 
def      emp_id           data_field2
def      dept_id          data_field3
def      ph_no            data_field1
```

I want result like below,

Result_Table

```
Type     emp_id    dept_id    ph_no
------------------------------------------------
abc      1234       5678      4321
def      1235       9877      5679
```

I tried like below,

```
Select Case when type='abc' then data_field1 
            when type='def' then data_field2 end emp_id,
       case when type='abc' then data_field2
            when type='def' then data_field3 end dept_id,
       case when type='abc' then data_field3
            when type='def' then data_field1 end ph_no
from data_table;
```

I manually checked the TYPE and DESTINATION of particular ATTRIBUTE from MAPPING_TABLE and made above query. The problem is I am having more than 50 TYPE and for each TYPEs almost 100 ATTRIBUTEs. So I cannot make the query like above for all types.

So expecting an easy or better solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Maybe use some sort of PIVOT, but that is not a very good table design.

Comment: What if for another type like "def", there is a different mapping between Attribute and destination then what should be the outcome. Let's say the mapping for "def" is ph_no --> Data_field1, what you are expecting in this situation? One more thing, Is there the same Attributes available for all the TYPE? Can you please edit your question to make it for only 3 Data_field and 3 TYPEs and your expected result?

Comment: You are ryt Tejash. Exact scenario only I am having. Thank you for the suggestion. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with above comments that this is not a good table design, however if you have no choice but to work with this then I would be inclined to go with a dynamic SQL solution (below is untested and may contain syntax errors but should be good starting point).

This solution assumes that all types will have the same fields (and all types will have a definition for all fields).

Once you have built up the string using the below you can use execute immediate to select it into a table type, or use it in a loop to iterate through, or whatever else you need to do with it.

```
declare
  v_sql_string varchar2(32000);
  v_first_row boolean default true;      
  v_current_type varchar2(3) default null;

  cursor c_types is 
  select * from mapping_table
  order by type, attribute;

begin
  for v_row in c_mappings loop
    if v_fisrt_row then
       v_sql_string := 'Select ';
       v_current_type := v_row.type;
    else 
       if v_curent_type != v_row.type then           
         v_sql_string := 'Union select ';
       end if;
    end if;

    if v_first_row then
      v_sql_string := v_sql_string || ' as ' || attribute ';
    else
      v_sql_string := ', ' || v_sql_string || ' as ' || attribute ';
    end if;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql_string);  
end;
/
```